# Error while posting an activity to yammer via API

Tags: json, api, yammer

I am integrating yammer in my project and I am trying to post some content to wall of user in Yammer network.

I sent post request to https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/activity.json

Set content-type and authorization headers and sent following json :

```
{
"activity":{
"actor":{"name":"Rajat Nigam",
"email":"rajat@abc.in"},
"action":"create",
"object": {
"url":"https://d3rnbxvnd0hlox.cloudfront.net/images/channels/49/icons/large.png",
"title":"Test"
},
"message":"Hey, let’s test!"
}
}
```

In response i received

```
{
  "action_id": 12567279,
  "object_id": 351561207270636,
  "actor_id": 1552299723
}
```

But when i check my wall on yammer, i couldn't find any post.

Am I missing something?